# SassAndCoffee compiles CoffeeScript with the 'bare' option. Can I control this?

Tags: coffeescript

If I install the SassAndCoffee.Core package from NuGet, and then ask SassAndCoffee to compile some CoffeeScript, it seems to pass the "bare" option to the CoffeeScript compiler -- i.e., it does not wrap my script in CoffeeScript's usual `(function() {` and `}).call(this);` bookends.

**Is there a way I can make SassAndCoffee *not* use the "bare" option?**

Note: this is in a desktop app, and I'm explicitly calling into SassAndCoffee's code -- this is not the magic rewriting that happens in an ASP.NET site.

More details: Here's my code to compile CoffeeScript using SassAndCoffee.

```
var sassCompiler = new CoffeeScriptCompiler();
var js = sassCompiler.Compile("alert 'Hello World'");
```

which results in the following (bare) output in the `js` variable:

```
alert('Hello World');
```

But if I write some straightforward JavaScript that calls the [official CoffeeScript compiler](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/) with the default options, e.g. this HTML file (drop [coffee-script.js](https://raw.github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/1a652a9736e104359251107f92b6e97409bdb5de/extras/coffee-script.js) into the same directory):

```
<script src="coffee-script.js"></script>
<script>
document.write("<pre>")
document.write(CoffeeScript.compile("alert 'Hello World'"))
document.write("</pre>")
</script>
```

I get the expected, wrapped JavaScript output:

```
(function() {
  alert('Hello World');
}).call(this);
```

It looks like SassAndCoffee is calling `CoffeeScript.compile(input, {bare: true})` instead of just `CoffeeScript.compile(input)`.

I'd like to use SassAndCoffee.Core for its V8 support, but I want to be able to choose between default output and bare output. Short of rewriting SassAndCoffee's CoffeeScript compiler (which would kinda defeat the point of using SassAndCoffee), or manually prepending and appending the wrapper code (I'd feel dirty duplicating work that the compiler is supposed to do), is there any way I can get SassAndCoffee to output non-bare JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading this right, it seems to be an explicit decision by the developers:

https://github.com/xpaulbettsx/SassAndCoffee/blob/43300b7805db8b3dccf20cc71d1282ecfd8c76e1/SassAndCoffee.Core/CoffeeScript/coffee-script.js

That might also provide you the file you need to change to modify it to your needs.

As an alternative, in case you get stuck, I use [Mindscape Web Workbench](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench) as a Visual Studio plugin that seems to do most of what it appears SassAndCoffee accomplishes for you.

Comment: I actually do want to compile the CoffeeScript at runtime, not in the IDE, and it doesn't look like Mindscape Web Workbench lets me do that. Still, the ultimate answer here seems to be "No, there's (currently) no way to get SassAndCoffee to output non-bare JavaScript", which fits with what I heard from the author.